# How to Configure view locals in action as machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, ejs

I am rockie in sails and kick start with action 2(action as machine). I am stuck how to configure view locals in actions 2.
For instance, in standalone action I can configure and add layout to view by the below snippet:

```
res.view('./pages/coffee/Boss/sell', { layout: 'layouts/layout-boss' })
```

My question is How can we do the same thing with action as machine(action2) ?

```
exits: {
    success: {
      responseType: "view",
      viewTemplatePath: './pages/coffee/Boss/listDrink'
      //Here I want to configure locals of view
      //Specifically, I want to configure layout of the view
    },
    notFound: {
      description: 'The data of drinks are empty',
      respondType: 'notFound'
    }
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can set any specific parameters in the exits.success call, like the layout or any ejs local variables you might need in the template:

```
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

  return exits.success({layout: 'layouts/layout-boss', ejsLocalVariable: 'value'});

}
```

and the exit declaration would just be

```
exits: {
  success: {
    responseType: "view",
    viewTemplatePath: './pages/coffee/Boss/listDrink'
  },
  notFound: {
    description: 'The data of drinks are empty',
    respondType: 'notFound'
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

In SailsJS, to apply a layout to a template in an actions2 object you can do the following:

1. Declare your success exit as usual:

```
exits: {
  success: {
    responseType: 'view',
    viewTemplatePath: 'pages/hello',
  },
},
```

2. When returning from your method , add the layout to any any other values that you are passing to your template.

```
return exits.success({name1:value1, name2:value2, layout: 'layouts/backoffice'});
```

As far as I understand the layout is another local, and locals are explained here:
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/views/locals